# Проблема с отображением layout'a

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-toolbar

Не отображается верхняя часть моего layout'a, когда запускаю приложение на телефоне, а в студии все хорошо отображается. Я говорю о той, где название приложения. Вот код класса ;

```
public class FileManager extends Activity {

    ListView listDirs;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_manager);

        String [] paths = {"/storage/emulated/0/", "/storage/extSdCard/"};

        listDirs = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, R.layout.file_list, paths);

        listDirs.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

[image: first_image]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Превью студии доверять не следует - она почти всегда показывает неправильно. Скорее всего у вас проблема в стилях - покажите их

Comment: Каким образом? Что еще за стили

Comment: Показать можно добавив код в вопрос через редактирование оного. Стили находятся в файле res/values/styles.xml